# How to get TestSet path with UFT12/ALM12?

Tags: automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft, alm, hp-quality-center

I'm trying to get the Test Set path of a ALM12 test set with UFT12 OTA API.

I've just upgrade from QTP11 to UFT12.

On QTP11, we used to get the `TestSet` path like this:

```
Set testLabFolder = currentTestSet.TestSetFolder
Set currentTestSet = QCUtil.currentTestSet
```

But now, on UFT12, this doesn't work anymore.

According to the OTA API, the 1TestSetFolder1 was replaced by 1TestLabFolder1, and I tried this:

```
Set currentTestSet = QCUtil.currentTestSet
Set testLabFolder = currentTestSet.TestLabFolder
```

But I'm not being able to use this, I got the error:

> Object required: 'currentTestSet' Line (75): "Set testLabFolder = currentTestSet.TestLabFolder"

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just managed to solve the problem by installing a new patch to UFT12, find the solution details here:
[How to get TestSet path with UFT12/ALM12?](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/How-to-get-TestSet-path-with-UFT12-ALM12/td-p/6777671#.Vdz0cFWrSUk)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution.